# Obtain head and tail of nested list

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, nested-lists

I have a nested list type declared as such:

```
data NestedList a 
= Int a
| List [NestedList a]
deriving (Show, Eq)
```

I am trying to get the head and tail of a NestedList, but I'm not sure how it can be achieved. My attempt wasn't really successful, as it wil get the first Int in the NestedList. My code is:

```
headList :: NestedList a -> NestedList a
headList (Int x) = Int x
headList (List x) = head $ map headList x
```

I understand why this doesn't work, because it iterates over all Lists and gets the Int from each one. So for example:

```
test = List [List [Int 5]] -> headList test = Int 5, instead of List [Int 5]
```

I guess the solution for tail would be similar (except for the list instead of an element part), so can anyone help me get the `headList` working at least?

Comment: Is this homework? To me, it seems like you are already guessing so much that you do not know what you are doing in the first place. What does head and tail mean to you? Do you even know what a list is? Or an Int? (You could replace the names Int and List with Foo and Bar, it would still work the same and would be less confusing.)

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you mean by "What does head and tail mean to you?", but I am looking to make something that works just like car and cdr in Racket, meaning return the first element or - for cdr - a list of everything but the first element.

Comment: To add to my answer, @comonad, this is not homework and I am indeed guessing based on what I found on other SO posts, because I don't understand much from the available documentation - any Google search for "nested list in haskell" gives me 10 pages of flattening lists (which is what I tried to use as a base for the headList function and clearly did not work).

Comment: haskell lists are like this: `data List a = Cons a (List a) | Nil` but written syntactically more cute: `data [] a = (:) a ([] a) | []` where `(:)` is cons and that rightmost `[]` is Nil. you did write the two names Int and List, which are not types but the constructor names you did define. so your `NestedList a` contains elements of type `a` instead of Int, and a `NestedList String` could be i.e. an `Int "Hello"` or an `List []` or `List [List [],Int ""]`. Your function headList returns not an element but a NestedList. The nested list you might want could probably be the type `[[a]]` instead

Comment: as a lisp programmer, you might be more interested in skimming the language spec than reading random SO questions. see the haskell language report about the list library: https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch20.html or hoogle: https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=head or the library for lists: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-List.html

Comment: It seems like you just want `headList (List (x:_)) = x`

Comment: Don't make head/tail functions, though - they are partial. Use pattern matching or NestedList's variant of `uncons :: [a] -> Maybe (a, [a])` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `NestedList` of `a`s is an atom of `a`, marked by `Int` (let's use `A` instead) or a nested list of `a`s (let's use `N` for that):

```
data NestedList a = A a | N [NestedList a]
       deriving (Show, Eq)
```

So, what's an empty list? -- It's `N[ ]`. It has no head or tail.

What's a singleton list? -- If it's either `A x` or `N[A x]`, its head is just `x`.

What's a tail of a singleton list? -- It's an empty list.

What's a tail of a longer list `N(h:t)`? -- If `h` is `A _`, it's `N t`.

The other cases where you have  more nested structure are more involved. Do you want your `head` to return the left-most atom in such cases, and `tail` to construct a similarly-nested structure without the left-most element in it? This can be done recursively:

```
headNested (A x) = x
headNested (N xs) = headNested (head xs)
```

Right? Not that simple, as [user Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi) points out in the comments: what about the nested empty lists case, `N[ N[ ], N[ ]]`? Is it to be considered empty too? (probably, yes). So this will have to be more involved. Perhaps you'd want to decide on some kind of canonical structure, and implement a `normalize` routine, to be used first.

Or better yet, keep the structure as is and instead follow [the other advice in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36683204/obtain-head-and-tail-of-nested-list/36688819#comment60965327_36683204), switch to returning the `Maybe` pair of head and tail, and use *that* recursively.

Comment: Also, consider the case `N [N [], N []]` - is that an empty list as well?